# почастичное высветление строки из базы данных в разных тэгах

Tags: php, html

В базе данных у меня есть строка:

```
hello, man
  `code` 
std::cout << "hi";
  `endcode` 
how are you, man?
  `code` 
std::cout << "i am fine";
  `endcode` 
thanks, bye
```

Как я пытаюсь вывести её из базы данных:

---

hello, man

```
std::cout << "hi";
```

how are you, man?

```
std::cout << "i am fine";
```

thanks, bye

---

Как получилось:
[image: content&code]

Код:

```
<?php
$content_array = explode(" ", $row_question_information["content"]);
// print_r($content_array);
for ($i=0; $i < count($content_array); $i++) { 
  if ($content_array[$i] == "`code`")
    echo "<pre><code>";
  if ($content_array[$i] == "`endcode`")
    echo "</code></pre>";
  if ($content_array[$i] == "`code`" || $content_array[$i] == "`endcode`")
    continue;
  echo $content_array[$i] . " ";
}
?>
```

Так же я должен писать `` `code` `` для поиска открывающего тэга, и `` `endcode` `` - для закрывающего тэга, так как я не знаю как мне с помощью одинаковых символов искать открывающиеся и закрывающиеся тэги, и к тому же я должен еще выделять `` `code` `` и `` `endcode` `` с обоих сторон пробелами, что бы это у меня был отдельный элемент массива. Хотелось бы услышать советы как можно улучшить мою работу.

Comment: зачем во всей этой истории вообще массив и копание в нем?

Comment: а как мне иначе переберать строку символов?

Comment: если вам надо при выводе просто заменить `code/endcode` на `<pre><code></code></pre>` то работать надо со строками, а не с массивом. искать вхождения подстрок в тексте и заменять.

Comment: а вот я например вывожу строку через функцию htmlspecialchars(), и у меня тэги так и выведуться, символами

Comment: а вы сначала сделайте спешалчарс, а потом замените тэги